# Create Actions From Tableau Map (with points)

Tags: visualization, tableau-api

I am familiar with how to create actions in Tableau, but doing so with map points has stumped me.  It seems as though Tableau uses the lat/long measures uniquely and different than how it would another measure.

The expected behavior I want is a user to be able to select a single map point from a Tableau sheet so I can use that selection to drive an action (in this case adding the selection to a separate, blank sheet).

Here is one workaround, but this isn't a stable solution for the end-user:

1) Find desired map point -> right-click -> keep only

2) From the new 'Inclusion' pill that appears under 'Filters'...right-click -> apply to worksheets -> selected worksheets -> choose sheet

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Vamsi.  I solved this morning a bit differently, it was actually really easy and didn't require any calculations:

- Used carrot on my map's toolbar to 'Use as filter.'
- Added a hidden crosstab to the same dashboard that, of course, changed to show the chosen map point.
- Used that sheet to power my other calculation.

Essentially, I had to have both sheets on the same dashboard which allowed 'Use as filter' to solve my challenge.

Answer (score 0):

(A) As each map point (generated lat/long value) is linked to a specific set of Geographic dimensions, you can create an index/combination of these fields as a calculated field. 
For example, if the fields "City", "State" are the geographic dimensions, create a calculated field

```
Index = [City] + ", " + [State]
```

After you create an Action filter from the map to the desired blank sheet, at the bottom of the "Add filter Action" window use "Selected fields" under Target filters and click Add filter. In the pop-up, select the recently created ***Index*** field for filtering.

(B) You can also just add the City and State fields separately into the "Selected fields" in the Action filter and not have to create the ***Index*** altogether.

In both ways, even if there are multiple rows of data for the same location on the map, the result would show all those rows.

Comment: Thanks, Vamsi.  I solved this morning a bit differently, it was actually really easy and didn't require any calculations:

- Used carrot on my map's toolbar to 'Use as filter.'
- Added a hidden crosstab to the same dashboard that, of course, changed to show the chosen map point.
- Used that sheet to power my other calculation.

Essentially, I had to have both sheets on the same dashboard which allowed 'Use as filter' to solve my challenge.